# UWP RichEditBox: How to enable HyperLinks for loaded RTF files (Document.LoadFromStream)

Tags: c#, xaml, hyperlink, uwp, rtf

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="RtfEulaViewer" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <RichEditBox x:Name="RtfEula" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsFocusEngagementEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
         Background="{ThemeResource StandardBackground}" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
this.RtfEula.Document.LoadFromStream(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, stream);
```

Absolute or relative HyperLinks in the RTF file that are click-able when it is opened by Word or WordPad, are just shown as normal text.

```
{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK "http://www.microsoft.com"}{\fldrslt Microsoft}}
```

from the RTF specification is displayed in blue colour but is also inactive. The mouse pointer does not change if I move over it.

Is there a way to get active HyperLinks in some text box when loading an RTF file?

Comment: In your code, you've set `IsHitTestVisible="False"`. This will disable all input interaction. That's why your hyper link is not click-able. Removing this setting or changing its value to `True` should be able to solve your issue.

Comment: Wow, I set `IsHitTestVisible` to `True` and this solved it. Thank you @JayZuo. Please add it as answer, it fully solved the problem. I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Thank you, I've added it  as an answer. Glad to know this helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you've set `IsHitTestVisible="False"`. This will disable all input interaction. That's why your hyper link is not clickable. Removing this setting or changing its value to `True` should be able to solve your issue.

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="RtfEula" IsFocusEngagementEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
     Background="{ThemeResource StandardBackground}" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```